# I'm trying to build a GTK app with Glade - is there a Python text-editor widget I can insert into my UI?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, glade

I want to build an application which will have an input field where a user can type in a very small fragment of Python code.

Rather than use a dumb text-input field I'd like to use something that is aware of the Syntax of Python - possibly even supporting highlighting or indenting. Is there any way to get this kind of widget into my application?

I'm using Glade with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you can use pygments for that ...

Answer (score 0):

Just try GtkSourceView. It is much like GtkTextView, with syntax highlight and  code indentation. Both Gedit and Anjuta use it to edit code.

First you need to install libgtksourceview-3.0-dev so that you can use that widget(GtkSourceView) in Glade.

Then in your python script, import GtkSource:

```
from gi.repository import GtkSource
```